# Toggle translation in a multilingual site

Tags: i18n-l10n

I'm building a bi-lingual site (English and French) with Drupal 7. I want to create a link at the top right corner of my site that toggles a page between English and French. How do I do this?

I have also installed the [Internationalization](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) module. I haven't used it yet. Maybe that can help my situation.

For example, say I am on the page http://example.com/home.  How do I figure out the french equivalent of that page, its URL, and print it to the right hand corner of my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the Language icons module. It will provide a block where languages can be toggled with a Flag. Btw the i18n (at least in D6) provides a similar block but with no flags, you can use this instead too and add the flags with a little CSS. HTH.

http://drupal.org/project/languageicons

Comment: hmm...languageicons doesn't seem to work in my version of drupal7 because of a bug. ok, trying the other option

Comment: I noticed a block called 'Language switcher' and used it.  Not sure if it's part of i18n module...